# how to create a webpage with responsive height for metro user interface?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, height

I want to design Metro User interface with HTML and CSS , and I want the boxes height change in difference devices. I use percentage for width . I know that it can be use for height too . but if I use percentage in height , if you shrink the browser vertically the height will smaller and bigger .

another problem is , if use multiple monitors together for viewing desktop , the width will be very bigger than the height , so the boxes will have smaller height and bigger width.

is there an efficient way for make a responsive web site in my situation?

**Note :**  I don't want to have a vertically scroll .

any suggestion or experience of making responsive in an efficient way? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `vw` to get the desired `height` in proportion to the view width for *small screens.*

**Then**, after the viewer exceeds a certain `width` - 1080px in my example, introduce a **fixed** `height` to the element using a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

This makes the element work well with both small and *extra,* **EXTRA** wide screens and the vertical size of the viewer wouldn't have any effect on it

```css
#logo {
  height: 26vw;
  width: auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
  #logo {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="logo" src="https://s.w.org/about/images/logos/wordpress-logo-notext-rgb.png">
```

Comment: thank you , but my problem is about height , I mentioned it in my question

Comment: @Parsamhn The same idea still applies. You can set the `height` in `vw` units. I edited the example.

Comment: Thank you very much , but what if the screen width is 3600 and height 980 , in that way my boxes width will be more larger that its height.is it ok? any suggestion? and another problem is if someone going to shrink the browser from height ( the boxes will shrink too ) what about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```css
div {
  /* 25% of viewport */
  height: 25vh;
  width: 15rem;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #eee;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div>responsive height</div>
```

Comment: I told that I used the percentage , vh means viewport height . it's same as the thing that I did. what about other situation that i mentioned? multiple monitors?

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }
.side-box {
                background:red;
                width:250px;
                height:100vh;
              }
```

```html
<div class="side-box">
    </div>
```